# How to divide two columns with different calculaton in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, distinct, calculated-columns, divide

I am newbie with DAX.
I want to divide 2 column, but seems the divide function does not work, because the value is not change.

This is what i've done:

```
AVG = DIVIDE('Backlog items'[score],COUNTROWS(DISTINCT('Backlog items'[Category])))
```

the result is always return the value of this part:
`COUNTROWS(DISTINCT('Backlog items'[Category])`

Anyone can give an idea about this?
I really appreciated it. thank you so much

this is my table looks like
[image]

The value of `Sum of column` comes from `Sum of total score / count of AVG`
The result supposed to be `0.67` but it shows `0.01`
I don't know which part that incoerrect :(

I guess the root caused is Total Score using SUM but AVG using Count, is it?

this is the table looks like
[image]

Comment: Should work. What's your sample data and expected result?

Comment: Dividing a SUM by a COUNT is no problem, but your screenshot doesn't help to explain your data model.